# How to create an INDEX of Join in codeigniter

Tags: php, sql, codeigniter, join

is there Any way to create indexes in codeigniter, try to optimize the join query...

```
  Without use of database caching
```

Answer (score 1):

You can extend the `dbforge-class` of codeigniter. have a look at this one:

[Codeigniter dbforge class](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/forge.html)

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think so. CodeIgniter's implementation of ActiveRecord only manipulates tables, it cannot alter the structure of the database.

A quick scan of the documentation offers no other method to create indexes through codeIgniter, but you may find someting I've missed: http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/index.html

You're best bet is adding an index directly on the database command line or via a GUI tool like PhpMyAdmin if you're using MySQL. This should improve performance on very large tables.